# Confluent - How to use external zookeeper instead of embedded zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I used to setup standalone [Confluent](https://www.confluent.io/) Server with embedded Zookeeper(ZK). But now, my prod server has its own ZK cluster. So I want to use it instead of the embedded ZK in Confluent.

Using `ksql` for example. Although I can set the ZK settings of `ksql` to my own ZK cluster and run the embedded ZK to another port and just let it be. But I have two independent ZK which make me "uncomfortable".

How can I make the embedded ZK "disable" and all the Confluent Servers use my own ZK cluster?

Comment: Are you using Confluent CLI?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I don't understand. I use `confluent start <server>`

Comment: There's no such thing as "embedded". It's just "local", but only because you're using the `confluent` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Confluent CLI is not for production use**. It is intended for use on a single node development environment.

You can see recommendations for [production deployment here](https://www.confluent.io/whitepaper/confluent-enterprise-reference-architecture/), and information about [configuring your services here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/zip-tar.html#kafka).